# Como comparar uma posição da string com um caracter ? C

Tags: c, string

A função processa_nomes não esta conseguindo comparar a posição da string 'a' com uma letra, estou querendo contar quantas letras 'A' aparecem na string e trocar as letras 'E' por um 3 .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int processa_nomes(char a[3][30])
{

    int i, j, cont=0;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<30; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]=='E')
            {
                a[i][j]= 3;
            }
        }

    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Nome: %s \n", a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<30; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]=='A')
            {
                cont++;
            }
        }



   }

    return cont;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[3][30];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um nome: ");
        gets(a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nQuantidade de letras 'A' na string: %d\n", processa_nomes(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note que a[i] não é um caractere mas sim o endereço para uma string de até 30 caracteres. Se quiser comparar strings utilize a função strcmp de <string.h>.

Comment: Mas como vou fazer para verificar, por exemplo, quantas letras 'A' tem em cada string ?

Comment: Se quiser comparar cada uma das 3 strings então utilize um for para a quantidade de strings e outro for mais interno para a quantidade de caracteres de cada string e daí utilize um if quase da maneira como utilizou: if(a[i][j]=='E'). Agora não entendi o que deseja fazer quando for igual no caso da letra 'E' , no caso da letra 'A' tudo bem.

Comment: No caso da letra 'E', cada vez que ela aparecer eu desejo trocar ela pelo numeros 3

Comment: Então utilize a[i][j] = '3';. Caractere '3' e não o número 3, pois trata-se de um array de caracteres.

Comment: Agora sim deu certo, valeu !!

Answer (score 1):

Como a resposta acabou sendo dada comentários, vou colocá-la aqui para futuras referências. Também diminuindo o número de loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int processa_nomes(char a[3][30])
{

    int i, j, cont=0;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<30; j++) {
            if(a[i][j]=='E') {
                a[i][j]= '3';
            } else if(a[i][j]=='A') {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        printf("Nome: %s \n", a[i]);
    }

    return cont;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[3][30];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um nome: ");
        gets(a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nQuantidade de letras 'A' na string: %d\n", processa_nomes(a));

    return 0;
}
```